# Whats the differences between NVIDIA installed from ppa or from nvidia.com

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ppa

Im actually testing drivers for my NVIDIA card from both the new **ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa** on the one hand and official drivers directly from **nvidia.com** on the other hand.

Installation and workflow in general is nearly the same i cant see any differences that far (except that the ppa installation is more easier).

But...

I also have Autodesk Maya with a student license and if i have installed the driver packages from **nvidia.com** all is fine and Maya is working fine.

If i install the drivers from **ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa** Maya will stop working for graphical faults and crash back to desktop. So there must be a difference between both drivers and how they work otherwise this wont happen.

I would like to know why there is a difference at all and why this happens for Maya for example.

Dont get me wrong its not a big deal to solve this by removing the ppa driver and install the one from nvidia, but i assume the main target from you guys over at “Graphics Drivers Team” is to build the nvidia drivers as close as possible to the official drivers? Actually they cant be used for Maya for example, where the drivers from nvidia can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the following:

On a new system installation (in my case 16.04) there are mesa drivers installed. The libraries for mesa are installed to:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl
```

During the installation of mesa symlinks are created from

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so` to

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libEGL.so` to

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so` to

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
```

If you install the nvidia drivers from **ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa** this will install the same libs but to `/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX`.
As the symlinks from mesa in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` will stay Autodesk's maya will use them. 
And as maya requires nvidia drivers to be installed it will crash because it loads the mesa drivers.

The solution is wether to tell maya to use different libs from nvidia or to replace the mesa symlinks with symlinks pointing to the respective nvidia libs.

Wouldnt it be a good idea to check the system about any mesa drivers installed during the nvidia installation?